# Login into Discord webapplication with js or Browser console

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

Hi im looking for a way to login into discord.com/login automaticaly with cefsharp

```css
       const string email = @"email";
                const string password = @"password";

                Boolean a = true;
                const string script = @"(function()
                    {
                      let element = document.getElementsByName('email')[0];
                      document.getElementById(element.id).value = '"+ email + @"';
                      element = document.getElementsByName('password')[0];
                      document.getElementById(element.id).value = '" + password + @"';
                      document.getElementsByClassName('marginBottom8-emkd0_ button-1cRKG6 button-f2h6uQ lookFilled-yCfaCM colorBrand-I6CyqQ sizeLarge-3mScP9 fullWidth-fJIsjq grow-2sR_-F')[0].click();
                      return element.id;
                    })();";
               
                    var javascriptResponse = await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);
                    dynamic result = javascriptResponse.Result;
```

i tried it with this snippet but it if its click the button the username and password fields  r not recognize the string in it.

i tried the same commands in my chrome browser console and it write the string on the website but not in the value field of the textbox element.

can someone tell me why it is not accepting the intput in the textfields

ty Sebastian

Comment: Most likely they're using a UI framework that syncs the values of the inputs to some state in memory rather than pulling them from the DOM at the point where the form gets submitted. You'd need to trigger the `input` event handlers somehow.

Comment: yeah had something like this in mind to but no clue how to find the input handlers and after how to trigger them is it something that i can find with the chrome dev tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution by changing the script to

```js
                   const string script = @"(function()
                    {
                      let element = document.getElementsByName('email');
                      element[0].focus();
                      document.execCommand('insertText', false, '" + email + @"');
                      element = document.getElementsByName('password');
                      element[0].focus();
                      document.execCommand('insertText', false, '" + password + @"');
                      document.getElementsByClassName('marginBottom8-emkd0_ button-1cRKG6 button-f2h6uQ lookFilled-yCfaCM colorBrand-I6CyqQ sizeLarge-3mScP9 fullWidth-fJIsjq grow-2sR_-F')[0].click();
                      return element.id;
                    })();";
```